# OWIN Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo() not working for linkedin but does for others

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Suddenly our "log in with linkedin" stopped working, for some reason Authentication.GetExternalLoginInfo() now returns null every single time, while facebook and google returns the correct result with login info. I have tried to debug the issue, but i cant seem to figure out why all the others work and Linkedin does not.

- In the startup.configureAuth the clientid and the clientsecret has
  been set.
- I have tried updating the .providers packet to the newest version.
- all the redirect url's seems to be correct in the code and on the linkedin
  developer page.

  - we are using OAuth 2.0, so it is not that either

I am running out of ideas to check or to try and debug, have anyone had a similar problem regarding LinkedIn, where everything else worked??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LinkedIn upgraded their minimum TLS version to 1.2.(ref: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/phase-two-our-tls-10-11-deprecation-plan-miles-mulcare/ )

Put this in the ConfigureAuth method of Startup

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Yeah i figured it out yester day: https://github.com/TerribleDev/OwinOAuthProviders/issues/242